# On an MSI laptop, how do I disable the backlite keyboard

Tags: backlight, msi

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on an MSI PX60 2QD and I'd like to disable the backlight keyboard, but have no idea where to start looking.

Comment: Generally: Fn + F3.

Comment: `xset -led 3` give that a shot

Comment: no luck with either of those Fn + f3 turns the touch pad on/off. I tried a few xset -led numbers buit nothgin happened, I'll see if I can find the correct number / name for that command

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mine is an MSI GL62.  I was able to do that with `Fn + +` and `Fn + -`
Took me a while.

Comment: Didn't seem get it work on mine.  Did you have to install additional drivers?  None of my fn+ [keys] seem to be working as expected.

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent the keyboard lighting up red when pressing the fn key.

Comment: on my GL65 the above worked, note i had to use the + and - keys in the numpad and not in the above row, and they worked in reverse as indicated in small icon on the keys, i.e. Fn + reduced, Fn - increase backlit keyboard brightness